# Failed to add android platform to an ionic project

Tags: android, angular, cordova-plugins, ionic4

IM TRYING TO BUILD AN APK AND I GET THIS ERROR

```js
Discovered saved plugin "im.ltdev.cordova.UserAgent". Adding it to the project
Failed to restore plugin "im.ltdev.cordova.UserAgent" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not found : im.ltdev.cordova.UserAgent
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'im.ltdev.cordova.UserAgent' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 Your package name is not valid, because
npm ERR! 404  1. name can no longer contain capital letters
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Desarrollo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-28T17_27_27_131Z-debug.log
Discovered saved plugin "cordova-plugin-firebase". Adding it to the project
Failed to restore plugin "cordova-plugin-firebase" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Failed to fetch plugin git+https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase.git#GH-1057-April-05-android-build-issue via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! undefined
npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Desarrollo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-28T17_27_31_601Z-debug.log
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: V7+
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to C:\Users\Desarrollo\Desktop\lugus-3-0\platforms\android\app\build.gradle
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to C:\Users\Desarrollo\Desktop\lugus-3-0\platforms\android\cordova-android-support-gradle-release\SanDiego-cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle
cordova-plugin-androidx: Updated gradle.properties to enable AndroidX
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter: Processed 18 Java source files in 450ms
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd platform add android exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

THIS IS MY IONIC INFO

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.15 (C:\Users\Desarrollo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.17
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.23
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.0.7
   @angular/cli                  : 7.0.7
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.2.0

Cordova:
   Cordova CLI       : not installed
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.5.2, (and 10 other plugins)

Utility:
   cordova-res : 0.9.0
   native-run  : not installed

System:
   NodeJS : v11.1.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 10

Comment: the npm package you need is `cordova-plugin-useragent`. Please clean and install node_modules with this and try

Comment: Also, please include your package.json for others to look at and help

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have wrong node-module name in package.json.

Please update your `package.json` to use  [`cordova-plugin-agent`](https://github.com/aaronneon2/cordova-plugin-useragent) , clean up your `node_modules` directory and NPM cache and install it again.

Hope it helps.

Also please refer to this issue [here on github](https://github.com/LouisT/cordova-useragent/issues/9) that has same info: